# Python runtime determine which module to load

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, import

I have my Python unittest script like below. It takes an argument '`-a`' to determine whether the testcases should load the base module from `foo_PC_A.py` or `foo_PC_B.py`. I use `shutil.move()` to rename either .py file to foo.py, so all the testcase modules (e.g. `tm1.py`, `tm2.py`) can simply `import foo`. Though this looks like a workaround and not Pythonic. Is there any better way to do this? Or a better design to fundamentally resolve this issue.

**(run_all_unittest.py)**

```
if sys.argv[1] = '-a':
  shutil.move('foo_PC_A.py', 'foo.py')
else:
  shutil.move('foo_PC_B.py', 'foo.py')


test_module_list = ['tm1', 'tm2', ...]
for test_module_name in test_module_list:
  test_module = __import__(test_module_name)
  test_suites.append(unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule(test_module))

alltests = unittest.TestSuite(test_suites)
unittest.TextTestRunner().run(alltests)

if sys.argv[1] = '-a':
  shutil.move('foo.py', 'foo_PC_A.py')
else:
  shutil.move('foo.py', 'foo_PC_B.py')
```

**(tm1.py)**

```
from foo import MyTestCase
...
```

**(foo_PC_A.py)**

```
import <some module only available on PC A>

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
...
```

**(foo_PC_B.py)**

```
# since the PC A modules are not available on PC B, 
# just call the pre-built executable via subprocess
import subprocess
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
...
  def test_run(self):
        subprocess.call(...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fool Python into thinking the module has already been loaded. Just import the module dynamically and use [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.modules):

```
import sys
import importlib

if sys.argv[1] = '-a':
    sys.modules['foo'] = importlib.import_module('foo_PC_A')
else:
    sys.modules['foo'] = importlib.import_module('foo_PC_A')
```

When any module runs `import foo` or `from foo import ...`, Python will use that path.

Note that if `foo` is moved to a package, the full Python path must be specified, as in:

```
sys.modules['path.to.foo'] = ...
```